# Es posible pasar desde codigo SQL a migraciones de laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel-5

Les cuento...tengo una base de datos muy grande, y la verdad es que no tendría problemas en codear 20 o 25 tablas dentro de las migraciones de PHP/Laravel el problema es que son 97 tablas la mayoría medianamente grandes...

Al punto... Existe un software, asistente o generador de código que me facilite pasar de código SQL a lo que serian las migraciones de laravel...

Seria muy aburrido y perjudicial para mi salud mental tener que hacer 97 tablas desde 0...

Desde ya muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo un software llamada [Xethron](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator)

Es de fácil implementación y va a solucionarte el problema a la perfección.

En su repositorio esta todo lo que necesitas para su instalación, configuración y ejecución.

Saludos